# Ignore specific File when using Xcode merge

Tags: xcode, git, merge, info.plist, git-merge-conflict

I want to regularly merge changes from my development branch to a specific feature branch to be up to date with recent changes.

Unfortunately when merging using Xcode it is complaining about a conflict in the Info.plist files which cannot be displayed in Xcode. So I have to change the files manually at each merge.

Is there a way to ignore all Info.plist files in a merge process? I've added and committed a .gitattributes file to the root of my feature branch containing

```
Info.plist merge=ours
```

This seems not to work as Xcode still complains about conflicts on all Info.plist files.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why does `Info.plist` always change? Not putting git-related values into your versioning properties are you?

Comment: Info.plist contains the Bundle version string which changes quite often

Comment: Syntax error in .gitattributes? Try *nfo.plist

Comment: Also thought about this but not, this doesn't fix the problem. Just for clarification: the .gitattributes file hast to be in repository root dir and *nfo.plist will also cover files in subdirectories?